# How to extract angular component output to an outer div

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-components, angular-template

I would like to display different lists (defined by a component), but display their headers only if a necessary `Output` is produced by the child component.

Say I have a component that, among other things, `@Output`s an event, like so

```
export class ItemListComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input()
  private filter: (t: Item) => boolean;

  private tasks: TaskItem[];

  @Output()
  isEmpty = new EventEmitter();
```

In my other component I display this list, by injecting a necessary `filter`, like so

```html
<div> list header  <-- I would love to hide that -->
<app-item-list [filter]="filter" *ngIf="!(isEmpty)">
</app-item-list>
</div>
```

I can hide the item list depending on the `(isEmpty)`, but can I hide the `div` above?

Comment: when you want to hide the div ?

Comment: Please reproduce the issue on stackblitz. It helps contributors to help you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a variable in `.parent.ts` to hide and show your `div`

item-list.component.ts

```
export class ItemListComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input()
  private filter: (t: Item) => boolean;

  private tasks: TaskItem[];

  @Output()
  isEmpty = new EventEmitter(Boolean);
```

.parent.html

```
<div *ngIf="isShow"> list header  <-- I would love to hide that -->
<app-item-list [filter]="filter" *ngIf="!(isEmpty)" (isEmpty)="myFunc(e)">
</app-item-list>
</div>
```

.parent.ts

```
isShow = true;

myFunc(e){
  this.isShow = e;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using 'div' you can use 'ng-container'.

```
<ng-container*ngIf="isShow"> list header  <-- I would love to hide that -->
<app-item-list [filter]="filter" *ngIf="!(isEmpty)" (isEmpty)="myFunc(e)">
</app-item-list>
</ng-container>
```